# Python calculating time difference, to give ‘years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds’ in 1

Tags: python, datetime

I want to know how many years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds in between '2014-05-06 12:00:56' and '2012-03-06 16:08:22'. The result shall looked like: “the difference is xxx year xxx month xxx days xxx hours xxx minutes”

For example:

```
import datetime

a = '2014-05-06 12:00:56'
b = '2013-03-06 16:08:22'

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ends = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

diff = start – ends
```

if I do:

```
diff.days
```

It gives the difference in days.

What else I can do? And how can I achieve the wanted result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding timedelta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749294/understanding-timedelta)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use a `relativedelta` from the [dateutil package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/). This will take into account leap years and other quirks.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

a = '2014-05-06 12:00:56'
b = '2013-03-06 16:08:22'

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ends = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

diff = relativedelta(start, ends)

>>> print "The difference is %d year %d month %d days %d hours %d minutes" % (diff.years, diff.months, diff.days, diff.hours, diff.minutes)
The difference is 1 year 1 month 29 days 19 hours 52 minutes
```

You might want to add some logic to print for e.g. "2 years" instead of "2 year".

Answer (score 10):

diff is a `timedelta` instance.

for python2, see:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

for python 3, see:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

from docs:

timdelta instance attributes (read-only):

- days
- seconds
- microseconds

timdelta instance methods:

- total_seconds()

timdelta class attributes are:

- min
- max
- resolution

You can use the `days` and `seconds` instance attributes to calculate what you need.

for example:

```
import datetime

a = '2014-05-06 12:00:56'
b = '2013-03-06 16:08:22'

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ends = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

diff = start - ends

hours = int(diff.seconds // (60 * 60))
mins = int((diff.seconds // 60) % 60)
```

Comment: thanks, Corey Goldberg. your original reply is very useful too.

Comment: The example is not working, it says the difference between the two date is just 19 hours ... obviously, '2014-05-06' and '2013-03-06' is not the case.

Comment: Tong, since he used `seconds`, that excludes the amount calculated with `days`, so it would be `diff.days` ( = 425) plus that 19 hours

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the difference between the timestamps:

```
from time import time

def timestamp_from_seconds(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds

print("\n%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds" % timestamp_from_seconds(abs(1680375128- time())))
```

output: 1 days, 19 hours, 19 minutes, 55 seconds