# How do I get an age in years and date on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-dateutil, relativedelta

Here's my data

```
Customer_id    Date-of-birth
1              1992-07-02
2              1991-07-03
```

Here's my code

```
import datetime as dt
df['now'] = dt.datetime.now()
df['age'] = df['now'].dt.date - df['Date-of-birth']
```

Here's the result

```
Customer_id    Date-of-birth     age
1              1992-07-02        xxxx days
2              1991-07-03        xxxx days
```

The result that I want is

```
Customer_id    Date-of-birth     age
1              1992-07-02        26 years 22 days
2              1991-07-03        27 years 21 days
```

Just let you now, by `df.dtypes`, `Date-of-birth` is an object because is based on customer input in dropdown

How can I achieve this? I hope the question is clear enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25439989) with custom function, because count it is not easy because leaps years:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def f(end):
    r = relativedelta(pd.to_datetime('now'), end) 
    return '{} years {} days'.format(r.years, r.days)

df['age'] = df["Date-of-birth"].apply(f)
print (df)
   Customer_id Date-of-birth               age
0            1    1992-07-02  26 years 22 days
1            2    1991-07-03  27 years 21 days
```

Answer (score 5):

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    diff = now - dt.datetime.strptime(df['Date-of-Birth'][i], '%Y-%m-%d')
    years = diff.days // 365
    days = diff.days - (years*365)
    df['age'][i] = str(years) + ' years ' + str(days) + ' days'

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Customer_id     Date-of-Birth          age
    1            1992-07-04       26 years 25 days
    2            1991-07-04       27 years 26 days
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use something like the following. Note that it relies on the fact that the average year has `365.25` days, so it may be a day off sometimes.

```
import datetime as dt

def year_days_diff(x):
    diff = (dt.datetime.now() - x).days
    return str(int(diff / 365.25)) + ' years ' + str(int(diff / 365.25 % 1 * 365.25)) + ' days'
```

Example:

```
birth_date = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(10000)
year_days_diff(birth_date)
```

output:

```
'27 years 138 days'
```

Comment: @NabihBawazir just make a for loop using `df['age'][i] = year_days_diff(df['Date-of-Birth'][i])`, or see/use Dahlia's answer ;)

Comment: Chage the amount of days in a year is by `365.25` first> any method by only using year function

Answer (score 2):

This could give you age by rounding to years.

```
ref_date = dt.datetime.now()
df['age'] = df['Date-of-birth'].apply(lambda x: len(pd.date_range(start = x, end = ref_date, freq = 'Y')))
```

Comment: will try this first

Answer (score 0):

Use `astype('<m8[Y]')`

**Ex:**

```
df['age'] = (pd.to_datetime('now') - df['Date-of-birth']).astype('<m8[Y]')
```

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date-of-birth": pd.to_datetime(['1992-07-24', '1991-07-24'])})
df["age"] = (pd.to_datetime('now') - df["Date-of-birth"]).astype('<m8[Y]')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Date-of-birth   age
0    1992-07-24  25.0
1    1991-07-24  27.0
```

Comment: Error: `TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<M8[ns]')`

Comment: Do you have string datatype in your dates?

Comment: For me its work, but why `1992-07-24` give `25 years`, it should be `26 years`. Upvoted, it helps. but still waiting better answer that give years and date