# Why does substracting datetimes give an OverflowError?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am trying to get an age and thus substracting the today's date from a date in a data frame.
So trying to do this:

```
(df
.assign(dob = lambda x:  pd.to_datetime(x.date,format='%Y%m%d'))
.assign(age = lambda x: x.dob - pd.datetime.now())
)
```

but I get the following error and don't see why

```
OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition
```

Comment: the assign/lambda construct seems a bit hard to read to me - why no simply assign new columns the "conventional way"? e.g. `df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and `df['age'] =  pd.Timestamp('now') - df['dob']`.

Comment: btw. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51491893/10197418) are some more ideas how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `dob` having only date and `now()` having date and time. `pd.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')` should fix it. It is formatting it in the same way your dob is formatted.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried this too and I get this error ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'```