# Subtract two times to get a duration Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

How do I subtract two times to get a duration in Python?

I have tried the following code below using datetime.

Input for start time= 20-07-2020 11:00:00

Input for stop time= 20-07-2020 13:30:00

The output I would like is 2.5 hours or 2 hours 30 minutes

```
from datetime import datetime

print("Enter 11:00 13:30 for a task starting at 11am and ending at 1:30 pm.")
start=str(input("Enter the start time:"))
stop=str(input("Enter the stop time:"))

format_date= "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
duration=datetime.strptime(start,format_date)-datetime.strptime(stop,format_date)
duration
Task1_start=datetime.strptime(start,format_date)
Task1_stop=datetime.strptime(stop,format_date)

print(f'Start:{Task1_start}, Stop:{Task1_stop}')
```

Comment: exactly how you would guess if you just took a stab in the dark `Task1_stop - Task1_start`  (ps you should probably consider using `date_util.parser.parse` to convert string input to dates)

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439279/python-calculating-time-difference-to-give-years-months-days-hours-minutes

Comment: date `20-07-2020`  - `day-month-year` can't match to `%m-%d-%Y` which means `month-day-year`. You have wrong order of `day` and `month`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date `20-07-2020` - `day-month-year` can't match to your `%m-%d-%Y` which means `month-day-year`. You have wrong order of `day` and `month`. So you have to use `%d-%m` instead of `%m-%d`

**BTW:** you have to caluculate `stop - start` instead of `start - stop`

```
from datetime import datetime

start = '20-07-2020 11:00:00'
stop = '20-07-2020 13:30:00'

format_date = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"

dt_start = datetime.strptime(start, format_date)
dt_stop  = datetime.strptime(stop, format_date)

duration = dt_stop - dt_start

print(f'Start: {dt_start}, Stop: {dt_stop}')
print(duration)
```

Result

```
Start: 2020-07-20 11:00:00, Stop: 2020-07-20 13:30:00
2:30:00
```

---

To format it you need to get total seconds and calculate hours, minutes, seconds

```
rest = duration.total_seconds()
hours = int(rest // (60*60))
rest = rest % (60*60)
minutes = int(rest // 60)
seconds = int(rest % 60)

print(f"{hours} hours, {minutes} minutes, {seconds} seconds")
```

Result

```
2 hours, 30 minutes, 0 seconds
```

Or you have to convert duration to string and then split it

```
hours, minutes, seconds = str(duration).split(':')

print(f"{hours} hours, {minutes} minutes, {seconds} seconds")
```

Result

```
2 hours, 30 minutes, 00 seconds
```

---

**BTW:** when you convert `duration` to string then it runs code similar to my calculations with `total_seconds` - I checked this in source code.