# how can i calculate time float microseconds in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want subtract `string` type time

```
a = "2017-04-15 21:10:02.026"
b = "2017-10-15 10:09:57.321"
```

I want `a-b`

please somebody help me thank you

Comment: Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) module. Specifically, look at `strptime` to first create your `datetime` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert them first to a `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = "2017-04-15 21:10:02.026"
b = "2017-10-15 10:09:57.321"

dt_a = datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
dt_b = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

print dt_a - dt_b
```

This will display:

```
-183 days, 11:00:04.705000
```

[`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is used to convert the string into a `datetime` by specifying how the string is formatted. Each `%` tells it where each part of the date/time is.

In your case, the formatting needed is as follows:

`%Y` - Year with century as a decimal number.
`%m` - Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%d` - Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%H` - Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%M` - Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%S` - Second as a zero-padded decimal number.
`%f` - Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.

Subtracting two `datetime` objects will return you a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#timedelta-objects) object. With this you can determine the [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds). e.g.

```
result = dt_a - dt_b
print result.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) you can do this way (see all the options with `%` in the linked documentation:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = "2017-04-15 21:10:02.026"
>>> b = "2017-10-15 10:09:57.321"
>>> oA = datetime.strptime(a,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> oB = datetime.strptime(b,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> oA - oB
>>> datetime.timedelta(-183, 39604, 705000)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749294/understanding-timedelta) `timedelta` should be returning `(days, seconds, milliseconds)` this way

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime` as following:

```
import datetime


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = "2017-04-15 21:10:02.026"
    b = "2017-10-15 10:09:57.321"
    a_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    b_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    print (b_time - a_time).total_seconds()
```

`b_time - a_time` creates a `timedelta` object which have multiple attributes which you can find [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects); `total_seconds` returns time difference in seconds.