# Python - How to subtract two dates string and convert the result to milliseconds

Tags: python-3.x

I want to subtract two dates and convert the results to milliseconds, I can subtract two dates but not sure how to convert to milliseconds, for example the final output of below code is '0:11:27.581293', I want to convert this to unit in milliseconds, example 12400ms like that, please help.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser as dparser
>>> stime='2019-04-23 04:22:50.421406'
>>> etime='2019-04-23 04:34:18.002699'
>>> str((dparser.parse(etime, fuzzy=True) - dparser.parse(stime, fuzzy=True)))
'0:11:27.581293'
```

Expected results: convert '0:11:27.581293' to milliseconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding timedelta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749294/understanding-timedelta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `total_seconds() * 1000`

**Ex:**

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
stime='2019-04-23 04:22:50.421406'
etime='2019-04-23 04:34:18.002699'
print((dparser.parse(etime, fuzzy=True) - dparser.parse(stime, fuzzy=True)).total_seconds() * 1000)
#or 
print(int((dparser.parse(etime, fuzzy=True) - dparser.parse(stime, fuzzy=True)).total_seconds()* 1000))
```

**Output:**

```
687581.293
687581
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below which returns the difference in time in `microseconds`. Divide by `1000`  to get to `milliseconds`.

```
diff = dparser.parse(etime, fuzzy=True) - dparser.parse(stime, fuzzy=True)
print(diff.microseconds)
```